# Как написать два конвертера: первый из String в Entity, второй из Entity в String Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp

Имею следующий класс:

```
     @Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANIES")
public class Companies implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "COMPANIES_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COMPANIES_SEQ", sequenceName = "COMPANIES_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    private Long companyId;

    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", length = 30)
    private String phoneNumber;


    @Column(name = "COMP_BALANCE")
    private BigDecimal compBalance;


    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID")
    private Cities city;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    public Set<Buses> buses = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    private Set<Drivers> drivers = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    public Set<Routes> routes = new HashSet<>();

    public Companies() {
    }
    ...
    }
```

Для него форма регистрации имеет следующий вид:

```
 <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="companyForm" action="/admin/addCompany/newCompany" class="form-horizontal">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="companyId" id="companyId"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="companyName">Имя компании</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form:input type="text" path="companyName" id="companyName" class="form-control"/>
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="companyName" class="help-inline"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="phoneNumber">Телефонный номер</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form:input type="text" path="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control"/>
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="phoneNumber" class="help-inline"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="compBalance">Баланс компании</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form:input type="text" path="compBalance" id="compBalance" class="form-control"/>
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="compBalance" class="help-inline"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="city">Выберите город</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form:select path="city" class="form-control">
                    <form:option value="NONE" label=""/>
                    <form:options items="${cities}" multiple="false" itemValue="cityId" itemLabel="cityName"/>
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="city" class="help-inline"/>
                </div>
                </form:select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form:input type="hidden" path="buses" id="drivers"/>
        <form:input type="hidden" path="drivers" id="drivers"/>
        <form:input type="hidden" path="routes" id="drivers"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-success"/>
                <a href="/admin" class="forgot-password" style="padding-left: 27%">Отмена</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

При попытке добавления компании получаю следующую ошибку:

```
    org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
Field error in object 'companyForm' on field 'buses': rejected value [[]]; codes [typeMismatch.companyForm.buses,typeMismatch.buses,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [companyForm.buses,buses]; arguments []; default message [buses]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Set] for property 'buses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.team.mvc.database.entities.Buses] for property 'buses[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'companyForm' on field 'drivers': rejected value [[]]; codes [typeMismatch.companyForm.drivers,typeMismatch.drivers,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [companyForm.drivers,drivers]; arguments []; default message [drivers]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Set] for property 'drivers'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.team.mvc.database.entities.Drivers] for property 'drivers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'companyForm' on field 'routes': rejected value [[]]; codes [typeMismatch.companyForm.routes,typeMismatch.routes,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [companyForm.routes,routes]; arguments []; default message [routes]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Set] for property 'routes'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.team.mvc.database.entities.Routes] for property 'routes[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
```

Подскажите как можно проигнорировать поля-коллекции routes, buses, drivers?

Контроллер для companies

```
  @Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/addCompany")
public class AddCompany {

    @Autowired
    CityService cityService;

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    @Autowired
    BusesService busesService;

    @Autowired
    DriversService driversService;

    @Autowired
    RouteService routeService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String renderAddNewCompany(ModelMap model) {
        Companies company = new Companies();
        model.addAttribute("companyForm", company);
        return "admin/addCompany";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newCompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCompany(@Valid @ModelAttribute("companyForm") Companies companies) {
        companyService.saveCompany(companies);
        return "/admin/allCompanies";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("cities")
    public List<Cities> getAllCities() {
        return cityService.getAll();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("buses")
    public List<Buses> getAllBuses() {
        return busesService.getAll();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("drivers")
    public List<Drivers> getAllDrivers() {
        return driversService.getAll();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("routes")
    public List<Routes> getAllRoutes() {
        return routeService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Контроллер для Drivers

```
   @Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/addDriver")
public class AddDriver {


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    @Autowired
    CityService cityService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    DriversService driversService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String renderAddNewDriver(ModelMap model) {
        Drivers driver = new Drivers();
        model.addAttribute("driverForm", driver);
        return "admin/addDriver";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/newDriver", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveDriver(@Valid @ModelAttribute("driverForm") Drivers driver) {
        driversService.save(driver);
        return "/admin/addDriver";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("cities")
    public List<Cities> getAllCities() {
        return cityService.getAll();
    }


    @ModelAttribute("companies")
    public List<Companies> getCompanies() {
        return companyService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Конвертер:

```
   @Component
public class CompanyConverter implements Converter<Object, Companies> {

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    public Companies convert(Object element) {
        Long id = Long.parseLong((String) element);
        Companies company = null;
        try {
            company = companyService.findById(id);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return company;
    }
}
```

После добавления удаление полей получаю след. ошибку:`org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [com.team.mvc.database.entities.Companies] to type [@javax.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute com.team.mvc.database.entities.Companies] for value 'com.team.mvc.database.entities.Companies@7999ad1a'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.team.mvc.database.entities.Companies cannot be cast to java.lang.String`
`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.team.mvc.database.entities.Companies cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.team.mvc.converter.CompanyConverter.convert(CompanyConverter.java:17)
at com.team.mvc.converter.CompanyConverter.convert(CompanyConverter.java:10)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:375)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:36)
    ... 81 more
```

Comment: Не использовать их в модели `companyForm`.

Comment: Может есть способ написать два конвертера, первый из которых будет преобразовывать в сущность, а второй в строку?

Comment: Определитесь, вам всё-таки проигнорировать поля-коллекции надо или обработать?

Comment: Поля удалил, только конвертация не работает

Comment: Покажите контроллер.

Comment: Добавил контроллеры и конвертер. Не думаю, что проблема связана с контроллерами, так как пытался удалить коллекции drivers< buses, routes но всё равно получал ошибку, так как он не мог привести сущность companies к String. Сейчас ищу спопоб, как написать конвертер, который в одном случае из String будет делать Companies, а в другом из Companies - в String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не передавайте в форму сущность, передавайте [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO):

```
public class CompanyForm {
    private Long companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private BigDecimal compBalance;

    public CompanyForm() {}

    public CompanyForm(Companies entity) {
        companyId = entity.getId();
        companyName = entity.getCompanyName();
        phoneNumber = entity.getPhoneNumber();
        compBalance = entity.getCompBalance();
    }

    // Геттеры и сеттеры опущены для краткости
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderAddNewCompany(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("companyForm", new CompanyForm());
    return "admin/addCompany";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newCompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCompany(@Valid @ModelAttribute("companyForm") CompanyForm companyForm) {
    Companies company = new Companies();
    company.setCompanyName(companyForm.getCompanyName());
    company.setPhoneNumber(companyForm.getPhoneNumber());
    company.setCompBalance(companyForm.getCompBalance());
    companyService.saveCompany(company);
    return "/admin/allCompanies";
}
```

Если полей много, чтобы не засорять контроллер их копированием, можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь маппером.

**P.S.** Советы по стилю:

1. Имя классу сущности принято давать в единственном числе. Не Companies, а Company.
2. У вас в имени полей класса сущности дублирование информации. И так ясно, что Company.id - это идентификатор компании, называть его companyId - это лишнее.
3. Контроллер у вас называется AddCompany, хотя выполняет не только функцию добавления. Правильнее назвать CompanyController и повесить его на /admin/company.